# Get ListItem Id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, listitem

I have a custom `ListView` where I show elementss from a `jsonArray` that I download from server. Now I want the user be able to "like" entries. So when he clicks on an `ListItem`, the database of the server is updated so ne number of Likes increases. To avoid that users can like infinte times I store a row in the SQLite Database with the position of the `ListItem`. This works fine until there are new entries in the server database, and the positions change. How can I solve this problem? Is there a possibility to get an id from a `ListItem` instead of the positon or something?
Here is my code:

```
getALlEntrysListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = getLikes(dbh);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                  /*check if Item is liked (=1) or not (=0)*/
                        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 1) {
                            dbh.updateLike(dbh, position, Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), 0);
                            dislike(position);
                            cursor.close();
                        } else if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 0) {
                            dbh.updateLike(dbh, position, Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), 1);
                            likeUpload(position);
                            cursor.close();
                        } else {
                            dbh.addLike(dbh, position, 1);
                            likeUpload(position);
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

/*increase numer of likes on the Server Database (the dislike method works the same way):*/
public void likeUpload (int position){
    try {

        JSONObject entryClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        entryID = entryClicked.getString("id");

        final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", entryID));

        new AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(ApiConnector... apiConnectors) {
                return apiConnectors[0].like(params);

            }
        }.execute(new ApiConnector());

        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: Instead of using the position to know if the user liked it or not use the id of the object "behind" this listview.

Answer (score 0):

List's don't have their own id's. It default to position. Your underlying item must  have a unique id, and when you have that you can override the getItemId method to return that Id.

```
 public class YourListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomPojo> {

 ....
 @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            if(listOfData!=null) {
                return Long.valueOf(listOfData.get(position).getId());
            }
            return -1;
        }
.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this way may help you**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (adapter.getId()) {
    case R.id.listView:
            YourVOClass yourVOClass = (YourVOClass) listView
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
                    }
                }
```